# Symbols used into generating MongoDB objectId

Tags: mongodb, objectid, database

I have read through MongoDB manual but still couldn't find what I need.
Is it only 24 alphabet letters and 0123456789 are involved into autogenerated objectId or "*id", Is there a chance that it will generate something like "jkfdfak*-123kjsd?" and which exactly symbols are not used.

Comment: NO WAY!  it will not append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using this data:

```
4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch
3-byte machine identifier
2-byte process id
3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

And the string representation is in hexadecimal.

If you want create your own ObjectId you must provide unique hexadecimal (0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+) string.

Comment: by 'must' do you mean its necessary ? because right now I use a completely different format and it's working fine.

Comment: @GrishaGevorkyan can you provide me an example?

Comment: I have 2 objects from User collection with their userId. I create a Follow object in "Follows" collection, where objectId is 'user1Id-user2Id' which enables me to find follow object without queries just by objectId